# how to get the output of 'system' command in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file and a field is a time stamp like `20141028 20:49:49`, I want to get the hour `20`, so I use the `system` command :

```
hour=system("date -d\""$5"\" +'%H'")
```

the time stamp is the fifth field in my file so I used `$5`. But when I executed the program I found the command above just output `20` and return 0 so `hour is 0 but not 20`, so my question is how to get the hour in the time stamp ?

I know a method which use `split` function two times like this:

```
split($5, vec, " " )
split(vec[2], vec2, ":")
```

But this method is a little inefficient and ugly.

so are there any other solutions? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [call a shell command from inside awk and pass some awk variables to the shell command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646819/call-a-shell-command-from-inside-awk-and-pass-some-awk-variables-to-the-shell-co)

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646819/call-a-shell-command-from-inside-awk-and-pass-some-awk-variables-to-the-shell-co/20648953#20648953).

Comment: @nu11p01n73R my mistake, already corrected Thanks

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I read the post you gave.  According to the method I should use `last_time_over_budget_in_hour="date -d" " +'%H'" $5 | getline` but it is wrong. The difference is `the awk variable in the post is just after the shell command ` but here the awk variable is in the middle of the shell command`

Comment: @nu11p01n73R No, but I just want to know a method in this way

Comment: @ningyuwhut i couldnt find any way to read the output from system command. As of the `0` you are getting in `hour` is the exit status of system, being successfull

Answer (score 5):

Another way using `gawk`:

```
gawk 'match($5, " ([0-9]+):", r){print r[1]}' input_file
```

If you want to know how to manage externall process output in `awk`:

```
awk '{cmd="date -d \""$5"\" +%H";cmd|getline hour;print hour;close(cmd)}' input_file
```

Comment: +1: Although the answer 'use getline' should probably be made more explicit.

Comment: Thanks, but when I execute this command I got an error ` usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]`

Comment: Yes, your are right, I changed a machine and it gets the answer! but  can you explain the `cmd="date -d \""$5"\" +%H" `, what's the backslash for? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `substr` function to extract the hour without using `system` command.

for example:

```
awk {'print substr("20:49:49",1,2)}'
```

will produce output as

```
20
```

Or more specifically as in question

```
 $ awk {'print substr("20141028 20:49:49",10,2)}'
 20
```

`substr(str, pos, len)` extracts a substring from `str` at position `pos` and lenght `len`

if the value of `$5` is `20141028 20:49:49`,

```
$ awk {'print substr($5,10,2)}'
20
```