# Redirect input for gawk to a system command

Tags: awk

Usually a gawk script processes each line of its stdin. Is it possible to instead specify a system command in the script use the process each line from output of the command in the rest of the script?

For example consider the following simple interaction:

```
$ { echo "abc"; echo "def"; } | gawk '{print NR ":" $0; }'
1:abc
2:def
```

I would like to get the same output without using pipe, specifying instead the echo commands as a system command.

I can of course use the pipe but that would force me to either use two different scripts or specify the gawk script inside the bash script and I am trying to avoid that.

**UPDATE**

The previous example is not quite representative of my usecase, this is somewhat closer:

```
$ { echo "abc"; echo "def"; } | gawk '/d/ {print NR ":" $0; }'
2:def
```

**UPDATE 2**

A shell script parallel would be as follows. Without the `exec` line the script would read from `stdin`; with the exec it would use the command that line as input:

```
/tmp> cat t.sh
#!/bin/bash

exec 0< <(echo abc; echo def)
while read l; do
  echo "line:" $l
done
/tmp> ./t.sh 
line: abc
line: def
```

Comment: You can say `gawk '{print NR ":" $0; }' < <(echo "abc"; echo "def")`, for example.

Comment: @fedorqui this is almost identical to the pipe usage. I am looking to put the commands inside the awk script.

Comment: Then you are looking for [call a shell command from inside awk and pass some awk variables to the shell command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646819/call-a-shell-command-from-inside-awk-and-pass-some-awk-variables-to-the-shell-co)

Comment: @fedorqui I am not able to relate that to my usecase. Please see my updated example.

Comment: It is getting less clear to me what you want to achieve. Could you indicate what is your final goal so it is more clear?

Comment: @fedorqui perhaps my (imagined) use case is far fetched. Does the second example make it any more clear?

Comment: @MiserableVariable I adjusted my answer for your second example.

Comment: Read http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe and http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fCoprocess and arguably most importantly http://awk.info/?tip/getline

Comment: @EdMorton I came across your excellent articles before asking the question but wasn't able to figure it out. Essentially the construct I am looking for is to redirect input to awk to a process in the BEGIN block, much as the `exec 0<` does in the shell script. Is that possible?

Comment: If I understand you, yes - `BEGIN{ARGV[1]="file"}` will cause awk to take it's input from `file`. The general form to add files to the list provided as arguments is `BEGIN{ ARGV[ARGC] = "file"; ARGC++ }`.

Comment: @EdMorton this as closest to what I am looking for. I want to use a process, not a fixed file, is there a way to do that? If not I can execute the command with output redirected to a temp file and then use the above. Not quite the same thing, but I don't need a stream processing.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Update your question to show sample input and expected output instead of just examples of commands you think could do whatever it is you want.

Comment: @EdMorton thank you for your continued interest :) The general case is: the current construct is `some_command | awk_script`, the construct I desire is `modified_awk_script`, i.e. there is no input to the process; the `some_command` is instead specified somewhere in `modified_awk_script` itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From all of your comments, it sounds like what you want is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    if ( ("mktemp" | getline file) > 0 ) {
        system("(echo abc; echo def) > " file)
        ARGV[ARGC++] = file
    }
    close("mktemp")
}

{ print FILENAME, NR, $0 }

END {
    if (file!="") {
        system("rm -f \"" file "\"")
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk
/tmp/tmp.ooAfgMNetB 1 abc
/tmp/tmp.ooAfgMNetB 2 def
```

but honestly, I wouldn't do it. You're munging what the shell is good at (creating/destroying files and processes) with what awk is good at (manipulating text).

Comment: This is almost exactly what I meant when I wrote that I will redirect it to a temp file. You are quite correct that this is abusing awk, my choices are (i) use a shell script with inline awk script (ii) use an approach as above. I will have to decide how important syntax coloring is to me :)

Comment: @MiserableVariable it's actually just a decision between doing it the right way or the wrong way. The UNIX philosophy is to have a bunch of small tools each of which does one thing well, and a shell to sequence the calls to them. There is some overlap between the tools and the shell in what you CAN do but if you just stick to the right tool for every job you get a much more concise, robust and efficient result every time.

Comment: with respect, I would like to point out that no such philosophical system can be entirely consistent and correct and there are cases where rules need to be broken. What you consider simple -- using a shell script and a separate awk script may be unnecessarily complexity under some circumstances. In any cases, SO is on the forum for discussing subjective opinions, and this is borderline subjective. I continue to be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you're looking for is `getline`:

```
awk '{ while ( ("echo abc; echo def" | getline line) > 0){ print line} }' <<< ''
abc
def
```

---

Adjusting the answer to you second example:

```
awk '{ while ( ("echo abc; echo def" | getline line) > 0){ counter++; if ( line ~ /d/){print counter":"line} } }' <<< ''
2:def
```

---

Let's break it down:

```
awk '{ 
       cmd = "echo abc; echo def"

       # line below will create a line variable containing the ouptut of cmd
       while ( ( cmd | getline line) > 0){ 

          # we need a counter because NR will not work for us
          counter++; 

          # if the line contais the letter d
          if ( line ~ /d/){ 
             print counter":"line
          } 
        } 
    }' <<< ''
    2:def
```

Comment: This works perfectly for my example but I am not able to figure out how to use other awk constructs with this. I will update my question with a more complex example.

Comment: BTW what does the `<<<` do?

Comment: awk needs STDIN to work, this just sends empty string, same as `echo "" | awk {dosomething}`

Comment: I wanted to avoid series of `if/else if`. I will make one final update to the question using the example using a shell script parallel

Comment: Fwiw, if you make it a `BEGIN` block you don't need the `<<< ''`.

Comment: So, I think I am an A- in Python; a C+ in Perl;  a total beginner in awk.  Just the act of putting something in double quotes calls a shell?

Comment: nope, but when you send the string to a pipe it does.

Comment: I am trying to avoid the `if/else if` block :(