# read line by line with awk and parse variables

Tags: bash, parsing, awk, while-loop, line

I have a script that read log files and parse the data to insert them to mysql table..

My script looks like

```
while read x;do
var=$(echo ${x}|cut -d+ -f1) 
var2=$(echo ${x}|cut -d_ -f3)
...
echo "$var,$var2,.." >> mysql.infile 
done<logfile
```

The Problem is that log files are thousands of lines and taking hours....

I read that `awk` is better, I tried, but don't know the syntax to parse the variables...

**EDIT:**
inputs are structure firewall logs so they are pretty large files like

> @timestamp $HOST reason="idle Timeout" source-address="x.x.x.x"
>   source-port="19219" destination-address="x.x.x.x"
>   destination-port="53" service-name="dns-udp" application="DNS"....

So I'm using a lot of `grep` for ~60 variables e.g

```
sourceaddress=$(echo ${x}|grep -P -o '.{0,0} 
source-address=\".{0,50}'|cut -d\" -f2)
```

if you think `perl` will be better I'm open to suggestions and maybe a hint how to script it...

Comment: I don't think `awk` will give you any significant improvement in time..

Comment: Use another language.  I have replace bash scripts with Perl a couple times for long tasks and the difference was **enormous**.  Shell is slow.

Comment: @sjsam why not? see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice

Comment: @vessel it would help if you add a sample input (say 3-5 lines) and show the expected output you need to append to another file... no need to replicate your full requirement, restrict it to say 3 variables

Comment: @Sundeep :Please note that I have used `significant` in my comment. For larger files `perl` is suggested. Also, the link you pointed out doesn't actually make a comparison between tools. It just discusses ups and downs of a practice.

Comment: apart from looping time, the various variables look like just field extraction with appropriate FS declared.. I'd say significant improvement can be expected from the info given in question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, I assume the following rules of the game:

- each line contains various variables
- each variable can be found by a different delimiter.

This gives you the following awk script :

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=","}
     { FS="+"; $0=$0; var=$1;
       FS="_"; $0=$0; var2=$3;
               ...
       print var1,var2,... >> "mysql.infile"
     }' logfile
```

It basically does the following :

- set the output separator to `,`
- read line
- set the field separator to `+`, re-parse the line (`$0=$0`) and determine the first variable
- set the field separator to '_', re-parse the line (`$0=$0`) and determine the second variable
- ... continue for all variables
- print the line to the output file.

Comment: This is great, I'm almost done, the only problem I'm facing is that I need to parse a variable coming from geoiplookup ipaddress, now I tried awk -v country="$country",  and FS="\""; $0=$0; CIP=$4; but how to notify each line to do country=$(geoiiplookup CIP) I'm getting a syntax error

Comment: OK I found my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20646819/how-can-i-pass-variables-from-awk-to-a-shell-command

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution. If you use `getline` and you have a lot of the same `CIP` values, it might be useful to buffer the results to speedup to program.

Comment: well there are lot of the same values, how should I buffer the results...?

Comment: It depends a bit on what you are doing, but you could have the following awk line `(buffer[CIP]==0) { cmd="geoiiplookup "CIP; cmd | getline buffer[CIP]; close(cmd) }`. This would buffer the result, i.e. store it in an array. If the value already exists, don't execute `geoiiplookup` anymore but just pick the result from `buffer[CIP]`

Comment: I don't how should I buffer geoip addresses as to compare them I need to run the " geoiplookup CIP," but there are plenty of other fields that are pretty much the same... Can I set them with buffer[field]==value and speed up the parsing of the logs?

Comment: The above lines, buffer on `CIP`, i.e. if I already encountered `CIP`, do not run `geoiiplookup` but take the output from the buffer, otherwise, store the `geoiipllokup` output in the buffer for `CIP`. Nonetheless, I do think that this problem should go in a new post.

Answer (score 0):

The perl script below might help:

```
perl -ane '/^[^+]*/;printf "%s,",$&;/^([^_]*_){2}([^_]*){1ntf "%s\n",$+' logfile
```

Since, `$&` can result in performance penalty, you could also use the `/p` modifier like below :

```
perl -ane  '/^[^+]*/p;printf "%s,",${^MATCH};/^([^_]*_){2}([^_]*){1}_.*/;printf "%s\n",$+' logfile
```

For more on `perl` regex matching  refer to [[ PerlDoc ]](https://perldoc.perl.org/)

Answer (score 0):

if you're extracting the values in order, something like this will help

```
$ awk -F\" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) print $i}' file 

idle Timeout
x.x.x.x
19219
x.x.x.x
53
dns-udp
DNS
```

you can easily change the output format as well

```
$ awk -F\" -v OFS=, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) 
                        printf "%s", $i ((i>NF-2)?ORS:OFS)}' file

idle Timeout,x.x.x.x,19219,x.x.x.x,53,dns-udp,DNS
```