# awk buffer variables to speed up parsing of lines

Tags: bash, awk, buffer, line

Continuing from my last post
[read line by line with awk and parse variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47259579/read-line-by-line-with-awk-and-parse-variables)

I want to buffer result of a field to speed parsing of log lines.
I tried
    `awk  'BEGIN{OFS=","}
{ FS="\""; $0=$0; CIP=$4;
(buffer[CIP]==0) { cmd="geoiplookup "CIP; cmd | getline buffer[CIP]; close(cmd) }
...
print "CIP,..." >> mysql.infile
}' $1`

but I get syntax error...

CIP=[ipaddress]
So I'm trying to buffer IP address(es) so that it will not run geoiplookup script all the time, as it's slowing down the parsing...

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: It's fine to link to previous questions but try to include sufficient context here for this question to be answerable by itself. It's not clear at the moment what you're trying to do.

Comment: It's more of a syntax error question, rather than what I'm trying to do actually... Anyway I edit question to make it more clear.

Comment: Do you have `FS="\""; $0=$0; CIP=$4;` just in the middle of the script, not inside a block `{ }`?

Comment: @TomFenech : thanks I did it but still get syntax error at `(buffer[CIP]==0) { cmd="geoiplookup "CIP; cmd | getline buffer[CIP]; close(cmd) }`

Comment: Now you have an opening `{`, but no closing `}`...

Comment: @TomFenech : I have a closing `}' $1` but includes the buffer() also, do you think that's the syntax error? I need buffer to be before print results...

Comment: Another quick fix, would be to put `if` in front of your buffer line, i.e. `if (buffer[CIP]==0) { cmd="geoiplookup "CIP; cmd | getline buffer[CIP]; close(cmd) }`. As I assume, your awk has only one rule,

Comment: If you want help fixing a syntax error, doesn't it just make sense to tell us what the syntax error message is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a direct problem with the buffering, as it seems to work in this example ::

```
echo "172.217.22.132\n172.217.22.132" | \
     awk '{CIP=$1}
      (buffer[CIP]==0) { print "Calling geoiplookup";
        cmd="geoiplookup "CIP;
        cmd | getline buffer[CIP];
        close(cmd) }
      {print buffer[CIP]}'
```

This produces:

```
Calling geoiplookup
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
```

As you see it is called only once, so the buffering works.

There is however a bug in your code, the following should work better.

```
awk  'BEGIN{OFS=","}
{ FS="\""; $0=$0; CIP=$4; }
(buffer[CIP]==0) { cmd="geoiplookup "CIP; cmd | getline buffer[CIP]; close(cmd) }
...
{print "CIP,..." >> mysql.infile }' $1
```

I think the main problem here is the understanding of the `awk` syntax.

In its simple form, you should understand awk as a `line` or `record` parser. The awk language is build out of a set of rules of the form

```
pattern1 { action1 }
pattern2 { action2 }
...
```

Which should be interpreted as : if `pattern1` is satisfied, perform `action 1` on the current line. then continue to `pattern2`. If no pattern is given, it assumes to be `true` and the corresponding action is executed.

In the first example above, there are 3 rules.

- `{CIP=$1}` states that as a first action put the variable `CIP` to `$1`
- `(buffer[CIP]==0) { print ... }` states that the second action (`print ...`) is only performed if `buffer[CIP]` is zero, i.e. the value is not yet computed.
- the final rule states print the buffered value.

I hope this helped.